# jQuery help button causes calling page action

Tags: jquery

I have a help button on a form:

```
echo '<button id="help" class="narrowbutton" ' .
 'name="help" value="">Help</button>';
```

and this jQuery:

```
$("#help").click(function(){
  window.open('help.html');
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

Clicking on the button causes the help file to open as it should in a new tab. But some action also happens with the original form so that it changes to a blank page.

How should this be re-coded to prevent anything happening with the form?

Comment: if you add a `'_blank'`paramater after the file name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odds are that your button is submitting a form and you're not doing anything to prevent that. By [default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button), buttons are `type="submit"`, so the easiest solution would be to change that to `type="button"` which would prevent the submission.

```
echo '<button type="button" id="help" class="narrowbutton" ' .
'name="help" value="">Help</button>';
```

Comment: I'd thought of that and tried it but it didn't work at the time. It does now!

Answer (score 0):

buttons by default are `submit` type
in your case just add `type="button"` to button tag